# Which factors to select from factor analysis loadings

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I ran factor analysis to drop the variables but confused how to read the result and  how to select variables from factor loadings[image]

[image: Factor Loadings]

Answer (score 1):

## Guidelines

Usually, there are some recommended guidelines for selecting a specific number of broad factors, which contain their individual specific items. Please note, they are not imperative but rather suggestive. Some very popular guidelines proposed by **Fabrigar et al.(1999)** and **Costello and Osborne (2005)** include the following **criteria for determining the optimal factor solution:**

> 1. Each factor must only contain items explaining at least 10% of variance in its respective factor (i.e. loadings ≥ |.32| in magnitude)
> 2. Each factor is recommended to have at least three items loading ≥ |.32|
> 3. Your Factors must be interpretable in a sensible way
> 4. It is recommended that your final factor solution has no items that cross-load on multiple factors with a similar magnitude. For example, if one item loads on Factor 1 and Factor 2 with the magnitude of .40, it is better to remove it as it measures two distinct factors with the same magnitude

## Assumptions

I do not mean to overcomplicate things for you but you would be recommended to check is your data is suitable for factor-analysis in the first place. Many researchers in social sciences fail to do that, but it is highly recommended. This can be accomplished by looking at the following metrics.

> A) The Kaiser-Meyer Olkin metric tests the sampling adequacy by measuring the proportion of variance in the items that may be common variance, within which values ranging between .80 and 1.00 indicate sampling adequacy **(Cerny & Kaiser, 1977)**.
>
> B) Bartlett’s test of sphericity examines whether a correlation matrix is significantly different to the identity matrix, in which diagonal elements are unities and all off-diagonal elements are zeros **(Bartlett, 1950).** Significant results indicate that variables in the correlation matrix are suitable for structure detection.

---

**References**

Bartlett, M. S. (1950). Tests of significance in factor analysis. British *Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 3(2),* 77–85.

Cerny, B. A., & Kaiser, H. F. (1977). A study of a measure of sampling adequacy for factor-analytic correlation matrices. *Multivariate Behavioural Research, 12(1),* 43–47.

Costello, A. B., & Osborne, J. W. (2005). Best practices in exploratory factor analysis: Four recommendations for getting the most from your analysis. *Practical Assessment, Research & Evaluation, 10(7),* 1–9.

Fabrigar, L. R., Wegener, D. T., MacCallum, R. C., & Strahan, E. J. (1999). Evaluating the use of exploratory factor analysis in psychological research. *Psychological Methods, 4(3),* 272–299.